# Javascript to validate date entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to `Javascript` programming and I am trying to validate a date entered into an `<input>` from a calender snippet which is obtained from an external `Javascript` file. I am trying to validate the date to check if the user entered a past date. If the entered date is a past date, then I need to print a warning message to enter a valid date in future period.

I accept input date field in following `HTML` code:

```
<input size="12" id="inputField" name="inputField"  autofocus="" type="date"     oninput="return dateValidate(inputField)"/>
```

My Javascript function to validate input date is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dateValidate(inputField)
{

 var v2 = document.getElementById('inputField');
 var pickeddate = new Date(v2.Value);
 todayDate = new Date();
 if(pickeddate > todayDate){
    return true;
 } else {
    alert("Enter a valid Date");
 }
}
```

But this code doesn't seem to be working. I want this Javascript function to be run when I enter a past date in the `<input>` field and tab out. I want to validate date when it is entered in the field, not when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

**HTML**

```
<input size="12" id="inputField" name="inputField"  autofocus="" type="date"     onblur="return dateValidate(this)"/>
```

**JS**

```
function dateValidate(inputField)
{
    var pickeddate =  new Date(inputField.value);
    var todayDate =  new Date();
    if( pickeddate > todayDate )
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Enter a valid Date");
    } 
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5yEL/1/)

Comment: To get the timestamp, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

Comment: I know what it does, but why do you use it? It's unnecessary, and you might want to reuse `pickedDate` as a *`Date` object*.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Heera. Worked like a magic. How should I identify to use onchange()/onblur() for my event? I was using onchange() for that and got stuck there. <br/> Abhi

Comment: @Abhi, Welcome! Actually both events work like same, when you focus out the element but the difference is that the change event fires only when the value changes. I think you can only use the `onchange` event.

Comment: Dunno how many times it needs to be said: using the Date constructor to parse date strings is unreliable. You have no idea what format the string will be in, or whether the browser will parse it correctly or not. Even the latest versions of the most popular browsers differ on how to parse ISO 8601 strings, so please, **do not recommend it**.

Answer (score 4):

It is not working since there is a issue in your code, just replace this:

```
var pickeddate = new Date(v2.Value);
```

with this:

```
var pickeddate = new Date(v2.value);   // 'value' should be in lower case
```

Since, it was not correct, the `pickeddate` was always `undefined` and code didn't worked.

Comment: Not `undefined`, but a `Date` object with a `NaN` value to be technically correct. But in the comparison that's the same…